# The RelativePanel layout control

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I hear RelativePanel and SplitView are new layout controls for Windows 10. What is cool about the RelativePanel put as concisely as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has all the answers but here is a summary as concisely as
   possible.

- RelativePanel defines an area within which you can position and align
  child objects in relation to each other or the parent panel. It is
  essentially a layout container that is useful for creating UIs that
  do not have a clear linear pattern; that is, layouts that are not
  fundamentally stacked, wrapped, or tabular, where you might naturally
  use a StackPanel or Grid. If your UI consists of multiple nested
  panels, RelativePanel is a good option to consider.
- Using RelativPanel's attached properties (such as
  RelativePanel.Below, RelativePanel.Above, RelativePanel.RightOf,
  etc), you can position a UI elment relative to another UI element as
  well as relative to the panel (e.g.,
  RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel).
- RelativePanel, used in conjunction with AdaptiveTriggers, can be a
  powerful tool to create responsive UI that scales well across
  different screen sizes. If you want to explore further on this, there
  is a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlResponsiveTechniques?amp;clcid=0x409) you can download and experiment with.

Answer (score 3):

- UWP is more focused on making a single app which will run on all the platforms. These panels are also called as Adaptive Panels. It has taken care of  [Adaptive UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx#adaptive_scaling) very beautifully in app development.
- RelativePanel is better than StackPanel to implement the desired layout for multiple screens using the same base code.
- It has attached properties eg. RelativePanel.Below, RelativePanel.Above, RelativePanel.RightOf, RelativePanel.LeftOf which is very useful for making the different UI for different Device family using the same code.
- RelativePanel is even more powerful when it is combined with VisualStateManager. You can see the example [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/04/building-adaptive-layout-in-windows-10-with-relativepanel-and-adaptivetrigger/).